# How to add a file thats copied from one directory to a folder in another directory thats incremented

Tags: batch-file, scripting, dos, move, xcopy

I am making a batch file that copies my Google bookmarks and pastes them into another folder ( Kinda like a backup) called " backup of bookmarks". I wanted to make the script run every day at the end of the day so I can always have a back up ( may make it a scheduled task), and so I inserted a command to make a new folder( inside of the folder called backup of bookmarks)  called " Backup" and have it increment by "1" every time the script is run ( ex: backup1; backup2; etc). I need help taking the file that I've just copied and have it pasted into the incremented folder. Here is the script, it copies and increments the folder, but I dont know how to make the copied file go into the incremented folder.

```
::this script backs up your Chrome bookmarks. 
::Checks to see if the folder exits and makes a new folder incremented by 1

@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName=Backup"
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
    '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
) do (
    set "name=%%F"
    set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
    if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%baseName%%n%"


xcopy "C:\Users\jnicholas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks"  "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks\"
pause

xcopy "C:\Users\jnicholas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks.bak"  "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks"
pause

move /y | /-y "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks\bookmarks" "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks\"%baseName%%n%""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using time stamps rather than sequential numbering.  Also here is everything in one command and it is user independent.

```
@xcopy "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks*" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Backup of Bookmarks\%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%\" /I /Y
```

This will copy both the `bookmarks` and `bookmarks.bak` file to a time-stamped folder inside the Backup of Bookmarks folder.

Comment: It should be said that the date stamps above depend on regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XP Pro or above then this creates a date and time stamped folder for your backups.  The date and time formats are independent of local regional settings on the PC.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"

xcopy "C:\Users\jnicholas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks"  "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks\%stamp%\"

xcopy "C:\Users\jnicholas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks.bak"  "C:\Users\jnicholas\Desktop\backup of bookmarks\%stamp%\"
pause
```